How might religion evolve in a detached spacefaring human society?
Three hundred years from our current time, humanity under a unified central government attempt to colonize beyond Earth. Having relied on pre-FTL travel to navigate their solar system, the means to use what is, effectively, wormhole travel is discovered, and numerous ships full of people and resources are sent through one of these wormholes to settle the other side.
Unfortunately, something goes wrong and the portal closes behind them, stranding this fleet of colonists across space and far from home with no way to return. They resolve to settle where they are and numerous star systems are colonized by a group that eventually turn towards feudal monarchism, but in space. Having carried their earthly religions such as Christianity, Islam, Hinduism, and Buddhism with them, they evolve separated from Earth for many centuries. Disregarding the possibility of the society abandoning faith, how might current human religions evolve in an monarchic civilization over time?
For additional context, this civilization is not entirely unified. Different portions of its space are ruled by different noble families, and while they are ruled under a singular imperial house, this does not deprived them of conflict or in-fighting. Additionally, there is light magic that developed after the arrival of the colonists that very rarely manifests in the form of some precognition and basic mind control (I.E. The Voice from Dune).

There is no way to determine the "correct" answer/s to this question.  Looking at the real world, just in the last few hundred years religions have been created (eg Scientology, Latter Day Saints), changed allowed practices (eg allowing women in the clergy) and suffered scandals (eg financial corruption and pedophilia).  With a vague description, you are asking for the result of centuries of change to multiple religions on multiple worlds where magic has been added?  Anything could happen, it is up to you to write the story of what "did" happen.

This would be a much better and easier to tackle query if you focused on one religion. You named four types of religion, each of which deserves its own query. Within those broad categories are tens of thousands of denominations, sects, cults, flavours and fads. You also don't tell us much about the dominant culture. Just looking at the last several decades of western history, we can see how radicalised culture can bend and shape some religions while leaving others standing firm. This is to say nothing of three centuries of time!

This is not worldbuilding. You're asking to know the definitive path of development as if it were scientifically discernable. That is not only impossible to know, it's expecting the universe to build your world for you. Your job as a worldbuilder is to decide for yourself how you want the religion(s) to evolve and then develop the world to bring that decision to pass. We can help you with that, but this question is impossible to answer VTC:Too Story-Based.

Power Families
All monarchies will generate powerful families and succession lines. This will likely have the greatest impact on your religions.
From Samuel Huntington:

The "Clash of Civilizations" is a thesis that people's cultural and religious identities will be the primary source of conflict in the post–Cold War world.[1][2][3][4][5] The American political scientist Samuel P. Huntington argued that future wars would be fought not between countries, but between cultures.

His desire was to explain the current conflicts in the middle east and how cultures that from our vantage points are incredibly similar (sunnis and shiites) have continued clashes.
Lacking a federal government with some form of democracy and separation of church and state, your colonist will devolve into culture clans. Each individual will seek out similarities in languages, race, culture, and religion in the groups they join.
Your monarchies would likely be the top seat of government and religion as it was common not too long ago. Then the people in power would engage in game of thrones like affairs to remain in power (bribing, kidnapping, convenience marriages, murder). Within each monarchy you would also have distinct families vying for power with likely different interpretations of the main religion.
It is common for monarchs to expand religious beliefs as laws and escalate to the nasty stuff like inquisitions and mass ethnic murder. Considering that the societies are space faring, they must be somewhat technologically advanced. This can also mean cameras in every home, social merit systems, and all around heresy persecutions.
Your magic would only serve to exacerbate the issue as every crown would frame your mages as miracles inside their religions to further validate their claims to power. I would guess that your mages would rise quickly in the church structures and would and up as counselors to the crown they serve. If the distribution of this power is random, that would mean each monarchy could have a mage. You could end up with cool standoffs between these characters with the purpose of validating which religion is "more right".
I kept this answer fairly agnostic of specific religions for a purpose. While different creeds would lend themselves more readily for cultural monarchies, the drive to unify under any belief system is a human condition. Furthermore, church cannons evolve. There is nothing stopping a "peaceful" religion from evolving into a brutal oppressive regime.
The key take away here is that the families in power will mold their respective religions to benefit their rule. Whatever the system may have been before they left, what will be in place is a new cannon with the purpose to strengthen their claim to power.
